# IIS 301 redirect specific url to another specific url

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

How can I redirect a url to another URL using IIS?
For Example:
I got **http://www.aplusprint.co.nz/List.asp?id=58**
Wish to redirect to **https://eshop.aplusprint.co.nz/product/wall-flag/**

I wish to one to one redirection which means when the id change the new url will change.

I create a test rewrite rule, but not working

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wall_mounted_flag" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="List.asp?id=58" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://eshop.aplusprint.co.nz/product/wall-flag/" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
 </system.webServer>
```

Anyone can Help me?

Comment: `<rule name="About Us Redirect" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="Aboutus.asp" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://eshop.aplusprint.co.nz/aboutus/" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>` will work

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it.

`<rule name="wall_mounted_flag" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="List.asp" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://eshop.aplusprint.co.nz/product/wall-flag/" appendQueryString="false" />
    <conditions>
         <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=58" />
    </conditions>
</rule>`

Need a condition